# Hilbert Transform in LaTeX equation

Tags: equations

I'm having a bit of trouble representing the following equation.
[image: equation]

Some attempts I've made are below.

```
\begin{tabular}{c}
\centering
$x \Rightarrow \hat{x}$ \\ 
$\hat{z} = 
 \begin{cases}
 \hat{x} \times 2 & \text{if} x > 0\\
 0 & \text{if} x < 0 
 \end{cases}$ \\ 
$\hat{z} \Rightarrow z $ 
\end{tabular}
```

Another unsuccessful option:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
x \Rightarrow \hat{x} \nonumber\\
\hat{z} = \begin{cases} \hat{x} \times 2 & \text{if} x > 0\\0 & \text{if} x 
 < 0\end{cases} \nonumber \\
\hat{z} \Rightarrow z \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
```

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The various `align` environments from the `amsmath` package are the most useful for aligning math content along one or more alignment points.  Centering of math is most easily achieved by invoking display math via `\[...\]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
x &\Rightarrow \hat{x} \\ 
\hat{z} &= 
 \begin{cases}
 \hat{x} \times 2 & \text{if } x > 0\\
 0 & \text{if } x < 0 
 \end{cases} \\ 
\hat{z} &\Rightarrow z  
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I surmise some of the upvotes are a reward for me refraining from mentioning `stackengine`.  Oops. I guess I just blew it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the speed in answering this raised question. I think that other solutions will emerge over time. However, this solution met the expectation and solved the problem.